# Silverlight project direction with diagram

Tags: xml, silverlight, diagram

Good morning everyone !

I've just started an new project under Silverlight 5 :

This project is about to create a simple hierarcical diagram and generate a XML file to export it.
Here is a sample of what I want :

[image]

In each a file or selection, etc... I would like to store some information (name, date,etc...) and it would be editable by a PopUpWindow way.
At the end of designing, user can be able to export it with all these informations as an XML file.

So, I'm here to ask you some suggestion to do it in easy way.
Thank you & Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way of course is to use one of the existing diagramming control libraries for this task!

http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=silverlight+diagramming+control

There are many good commercial libraries and open-source projects for this kind of task. Just choose the one that suits you most! Your requirements are well met by probably any commercial library and very likely by most of the open-source ones, too.